# Copy/paste to and from Windows Virtual Desktop

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, remote, clipboard, azure

The virtual machine here is not a *general one* but **Windows virtual machine** (WVD: Windows Virtual Desktop)  specifically.

- I can't copy/paste between the Windows virtual machine and my local Windows.
- I understand that there might be security concerns when it comes to web-based access, but I've even installed the native Windows virtual machine client tool (Remote Desktop client (MSRDC)), but I'm still unable to copy/paste between the Windows virtual machine and my local Windows.

There isn't much help I can find so far, except for unrelated articles like

- [I can't copy/paste between the Windows virtual machine and the Mac](https://kb.parallels.com/en/117984)
- [Copy and paste to a Windows virtual machine: Azure Bastion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-vm-copy-paste)